# Getting error while scraping profiles from a site

Tags: python, selenium, variables, web-scraping

Trying to get member profiles from a site. Some profiles have many of the elements missing. So, I put this in the `try:except` block. However that gives me this error.

**Error**

```
  File "D:/bni_pro.py", line 52, in get_profiles
    dict1 = {"Name": mem_name, "Industry": mem_ind, "Company": mem_com, "Member Phone": mem_phn, "Member Mobile": mem_mob, "Email": mem_email, "Social Link": mem_pro, "Address": mem_addr,
NameError: name 'mem_ind' is not defined
```

This is the code I am using. Kindly help.

```
driver.get('https://www.bconnectglobal.com/login/')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(15)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="username"]').send_keys('username')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="password"]')
password.send_keys('pass')
password.submit()
time.sleep(5)
def get_profiles(i):
    global header_added, mem_phn, mem_addr, mem_pro, mem_con, mem_email, mem_state, mem_mob, mem_city, mem_ind, mem_com, mem_name
    delay = random.randint(4,6) #Change this to bigger numbers later
    time.sleep(delay)   #Sleep between subsequent requests to avoid IP Block
    driver.get(f'https://www.bniconnectglobal.com/web/secure/networkHome?userId={i}')
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        mem_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="memberDisplayName"]//span[2]').text

        mem_ind = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="memberPrimaryCategory"]//span[2]').text

        mem_com = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="memberCompanyName"]//span[2]').text

        mem_phn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="memberPhoneNumber"]//span[2]').text

        mem_mob = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="memberMobileNumber"]//span[2]').text

        mem_email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="memberEmail"]//span[2]//a').text

        mem_pro = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="memberSocialNetworkingLinks"]//span[2]//a').text

        mem_addr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="memberAddressLine1"]//span[2]').text

        mem_city = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="memberCity"]//span[2]').text

        mem_state = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="memberState"]//span[2]').text

        mem_con = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="memberCountry"]//span[2]').text
    except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        pass

    dict1 = {"Name": mem_name, "Industry": mem_ind, "Company": mem_com, "Member Phone": mem_phn, "Member Mobile": mem_mob, "Email": mem_email, "Social Link": mem_pro, "Address": mem_addr,
             "City": mem_city, "State": mem_state, "Country": mem_con}
    with open('BNI_Profiles.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict1.keys())
        if not header_added:
            w.writeheader()
            header_added = True
        w.writerow(dict1)

for i in range(1,50):
    get_profiles(i)
```

Comment: I suppose `mem_ind` definition raises exception

Comment: @Kurohige what is the reason for that?

Comment: instead of use `pass` in except you could print the exception and have more information

Comment: @Kurohige The element is not present. Many of them are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function to manage exceptions:

```
def get_element(label):
    try:
      
        return driver.find_element_by_xpath(label).text

    except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        return None  # or whatever you need 
# usage
mem_ind=get_element('//label[@for="memberPrimaryCategory"]//span[2]')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_element(locator):
    try:
      
        return driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator).text

    except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        return ""
# usage
mem_ind=get_element('//label[@for="memberPrimaryCategory"]//span[2]')
```

Comment: Still give `NoSuchElementException`. When I catch it, even then it gives the same exception, doesn't pass it.

Comment: OK, Can you try this? It's actually Kurohige's answer but in case of exception it returns empty string so the variable will be defined

Comment: Yes, That seems to be working. Yes, It needs to be "" , instead of None. Just running it for a while to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of xpaths and iterate through it.

```
xpath_dic = {'name': 'xpath'}
var_dic = {}
for var, path in xpath_dic.items:
    try:
        var_dic[var] = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path).text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        var_dic[var] = None
```

Replace `name` with the keys from the final dictionary in your code example.